# C# Object properties comparison

Tags: c#, class, object, properties, compare

I have a class which is used for objects comparison:

```
    public static class ComparisonHelper
    {
        public static bool DeepCompare(this object obj, object another)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(obj, another)) return true;
            if ((obj == null) || (another == null)) return false;
            //Compare two object's class, return false if they are difference
            if (obj.GetType() != another.GetType()) return false;

            //properties: int, double, DateTime, etc, not class
            if (!obj.GetType().IsClass) return obj.Equals(another);

            //Get all properties of obj
            //And compare each other
            foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var objValue = property.GetValue(obj);
                var anotherValue = property.GetValue(another);
                if ((objValue == null || anotherValue == null) && objValue != anotherValue) return false;
                if (objValue != null && !objValue.Equals(anotherValue)) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public static bool CompareEx(this object obj, object another)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(obj, another)) return true;
            if ((obj == null) || (another == null)) return false;
            if (obj.GetType() != another.GetType()) return false;

            //properties: int, double, DateTime, etc, not class
            if (!obj.GetType().IsClass) return obj.Equals(another);

            foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var objValue = property.GetValue(obj);
                var anotherValue = property.GetValue(another);
                //Recursion
                if (!objValue.DeepCompare(anotherValue)) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

When using this kind of object:

```
public class myObject
{
   public List<TupleString> KindTitle { get; set; }

    public myObject()
    {
        KindTitle = new List<TupleString>();
    }
}

public class TupleString
{
    public TupleString(string code, string title)
    {
        Code = code;
        Title = title;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

myObject A = new myObject();
A.KindTitle.Add(new TupleString("A", "B"));

myObject B = new myObject();
B.KindTitle.Add(new TupleString("A", "C")); 

bool result = ComparisonHelper.CompareEx(A, B);
```

When instanciating 2 myObjects and try to compare them, ComparisionHelper throw an error in the DeepCompare method (System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : 'Parameter count mismatch.'). It seems the ComparisonHelper class cannot compare object List type property, how may I achieve this in the ComparisonHelper class?

Comment: That is most likely coming from an indexer. But I question your approach overall...you are recursing into types you don't own...in this case `List<T>`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I do, Indeed its my question

Comment: You're missing my point. You're no longer comparing data, you're now comparing implementation. Does the implementation matter if the data is identical?

Comment: I just want to compare the values of the the objects. If you have a better approach, let me know. Perhaps I was wrong